# How for loop works with Instance?

Tags: java, log4j

While searching for a method who actually writes log to file in log4j library, found below method

```
  public void callAppenders(LoggingEvent event) {
    int writes = 0;
    for (Category c = this; c != null; c = c.parent) {
      synchronized (c) {
        if (c.aai != null) {
          writes += c.aai.appendLoopOnAppenders(event);
        }
        if (!c.additive) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if (writes == 0) {
      this.repository.emitNoAppenderWarning(this);
    }
  }
```

But am not able to understand what is happening in for loop. Can anyone help me to understand what is iterating over here ? Never come across this kind of code snippet..!

Update:

I've code where it uses one method to log in log files. And within that method it calls below method which is coming from log4j library

```
  public void log(String callerFQCN, Priority level, Object message, Throwable t) {
    if (this.repository.isDisabled(level.level)) {
      return;
    }
    if (level.isGreaterOrEqual(getEffectiveLevel())) {
      forcedLog(callerFQCN, level, message, t);
    }
  }
```

And from here is forcedLog method

```
  protected void forcedLog(String fqcn, Priority level, Object message, Throwable t) {
    callAppenders(new LoggingEvent(fqcn, this, level, message, t));
  }
```

this calls finally `callAppenders` method mention on top. And `protected volatile Category parent;` is present in class Category where all above methods are also part of that class.

Thanks

Comment: Without an idea of your Java background, how would anyone know where to start - or stop? Please edit into your question what your idea is of what an instance of `class Category`is, and what purpose instance data member `parent` serves.

Comment: @greybeard, Question Updated..! Please check now..!

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you're used to see loops like

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { ... }
```

and understand that this iterates `i` from `0` to below `10`, i.e. `9`.

Maybe you found the syntax of this loop a bit weird, but never had any deeper thoughts about it. So, let's do this now.

- The first part `int i=0` is a statement that creates the initial state of the iteration. Here, it defines a new integer variable named `i` and initializes it to become `0`. That's why this loop starts with 0.
- The second part `i<10` is a boolean expression that decides whether to (further) execute the loop body. This one defines that the loop is to be repeated as long as `i` is less than `10`.
- The third part `i++` defines what to change from iteration to iteration. Here it increments `i` by `1`.

Now, let's have a look at the snippet

```
for (Category c = this; c != null; c = c.parent) { ... }
```

- The first part `Category c = this` creates a new variable of type `Category`, and initializes it to become `this`. So, for the first iteration, `c` will be `this`.
- The second part `c != null` defines that the loop repeats as long as the Category `c` isn't `null`.
- The third part `c = c.parent` defines that every next loop iteration uses the parent of the current Category.

Category objects seem to have a parent field, creating a chain until the top-most Category has a null value in this field. So, the loop follows the chain from the current Category up to the top-most one.

So, the iterations are:

- c = this;
- c = this.parent;
- c = this.parent.parent;
- c = this.parent.parent.parent;

until `c` becomes `null` (because some ultimate parent itself has a null parent). The loop body doesn't create or modify any Category instances, meaning that the loop just follows the Category parent hierarchy that has been established before starting the loop.

So, if you only used the `for (int i=0; i<10; i++) { ... }` pattern so far, you've missed a lot of the power and flexibility of the `for` loop.

Comment: thanks, Am able to relate with basic for loop now..but parent is a instance variable of class type (Category ) itself. Then who controls this for new value once the loop is started ...?

Comment: @Lenny: Java's [basic for-statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1) has three parts separated by `;`, the last one is the *`ForUpdate` part*. It gets executed just before re-evaluating the 2nd part: the *control expression*. In the code in question, this 3rd part contains just *one* expression: `c = c.parent`, which "makes `c` walk up the category tree". (For an intrusively singly linked list, `node = node.next` might walk the list.) Data members ("`instance variable`s") get `control`led by their instances methods, if that.